# Dependency inject a class with values from a config object?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

Is it possible to DI dependencies in Drupal 8 *but* initialize it with values from a config object?

For example, SoapClient requires [specifying the WSDL](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) when called. I have different WSDL URLs depending on what environment I am using (test/prod etc).

I know you can do this from the services yaml file, but I have not read of a way where you can reference a value or value(s) from a config object.

My ultimate goal is to create a decorator or factory for SoapClient, but I'm not sure which.

edit: updated with code.

An interface:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Factory;

use SoapClient;

interface SoapClientFactoryInterface {

  /**
   * Create a SoapClient.
   *
   * This method should prepopulate the SoapClient with values from our
   * module configuration so it is ready to use.
   *
   * @return SoapClient
   */
  public function create() : SoapClient;

}
```

The factory:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Factory;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Exception\NetforumException;
use SoapClient;

class SoapClientFactory implements SoapClientFactoryInterface {

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
  }

  public function create() : SoapClient {
    $config = $this->configFactory->get('iana_netforum_auth.settings');
    $arguments = [];

    try {
      if ($config->get('mode') == 'live') {
        $endpoint = $config->get('live_endpoint');
      }
      else {
        $endpoint = $config->get('dev_endpoint');
        $arguments = [
          'trace' => $config->get('enable_trace'),
          'exceptions' => $config->get('enable_exceptions')
        ];
      }

      return new SoapClient($endpoint, $arguments);
    }
    catch (SoapFault $error) {
      throw new NetforumException('Invalid WSDL endpoint specified.');
    }
  }

}
```

The class:

```
class NetforumClient implements NetforumClientInterface {

  protected $username;
  protected $password;
  protected $token;
  protected $authorizationHeaders;

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Factory\SoapClientFactoryInterface definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Factory\SoapClientFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $soapClient;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
   *   An instance of ConfigFactoryInterface.
   * @param \Drupal\iana_netforum_auth\Factory\SoapClientFactoryInterface $soap_client_factory
   *   An instance of SoapClientFactoryInterface.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, SoapClientFactoryInterface $soap_client_factory) {
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    $this->soapClient = $soap_client_factory->create();
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of what you're trying to create exactly? You could always inject the config factory, get the config object and pass it to the parent constructor. Or you could make a factory service that creates SoapClient instances that you then use.

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm looking for, could you explain a bit more? I want a soap client ready to go with different config from my config settings when I call my wrapper class (that uses the soap client).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which part exactly is unclear. There are lots of examples in core.services.yaml that inject the config.factory service to read a configuration object, for example this:

```
diff.formatter:
  class: Drupal\Core\Diff\DiffFormatter
  arguments: ['@config.factory']
```

The constructor for that then looks like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a DiffFormatter to render diffs in a table.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
 *   The config factory.
 */
public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
  $config = $config_factory->get('system.diff');
  $this->leading_context_lines = $config->get('context.lines_leading');
  $this->trailing_context_lines = $config->get('context.lines_trailing');
}
```

Once you have the config object, you get the configuration you want and pass it along to the SoapClient constructor.

Comment: It's weird, because when I created a factory for the soap client, the soap client started throwing errors about it not being an object, but a reference _to_ an object when I was using it. Perhaps it is something peculiar about SoapClient that I don't understand yet. The Symfony docs for using a factory in services.yml also threw errors, seems that it needs a key and not a path to a class.

Comment: It sounds a lot like this error, actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140917/object-reference-is-not-set-to-an-object-when-try-to-implement-abstract-factory

Comment: That's C#, that has nothing to do with PHP ;) I won't be able to help you as long as you don't share the the relevant part of your code

Comment: Hang on... forgot to stash that and had to redo.

Comment: Oddly enough - I rewrite the code and don't get the linked error anymore about "Object reference is not set to an object", but I posted it above. Is this the "right" way of injecting a factory?

Comment: That's one option yes. Depends on what you want. Now you have a low-level soap client object that you need to interact with. Instead of a factory, you could as you suggested also have an adapter/wrapper and expose higher-level API functions. Maybe thats what NetforumClient is. You could also inline the factory method into that class then unless you will have multiple services such as NetforumClient. But in general, this is fine, yes.

Comment: Yes, this is intended to be a wrapper to fill in gaps that SoapClient does not have that I need to perform while passing Soap calls through to it. Why does the `factory` key not get used in services.yml?