# Connect to Salesforce using wsdl in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I am trying to connect to Salesforce (SF) with wsdl to pull data.

I can't use SF suite module or Salesforce rest client service.

In the D7 file, I have:

```
require_once ('soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once('soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$sfdc = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection($curPath.'/enterprise.wsdl');
```

It create the connections without any problems.

D7 References from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_11.0_Getting_Started and learned to how to use it from here: https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/blob/master/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php

In the D8, I am trying to figure out how to connect to SF in the same way:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller\Soapclient;
$sfdc = Soapclient::SforceEnterpriseClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection('../../includes/soapclient/enterprise.wsdl');
```

But got the SforceEnterpriseClient class not found error.

Stuck on it for a while, any help will be so much appreciated.
Anybody knows how to connect to SF in the same way like this:https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/blob/master/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem you are facing is due to the way you are referring the library; please refer the [following question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242078/load-external-php-library-in-custom-module); they have explained how you should be using external libraries in Drupal 8 custom modules.

Comment: I don't think they are connected. What i did in my D7 was download the php files from: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit and use it but right now they don't have latest php version available yet so should i write my own soapclient class or D8 have some other way to handle it? That's my questions. Thanks in advance.